# How to add multiple condition cases inside Switch method?

Tags: php

Is there a way to include multiple cases inside a switch method in php?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes it is possible

Here is an example to start with

```
<?
      $i = 1;
      $j = 10;

      switch($i) {
            case "2":
                   echo "The value is 2";
                   break;
            case ($i==1 && $j==10):
                   echo "Your exceptional Switch case is triggered";
                   break;
            default:
                   echo "Invalid";
                   break;
     }
?>
```

Comment: What does this give with $i = 0 and $j = 10, and a case of case ($i==0 && $j==10) ?

Comment: Your example only works because $i==1 && $j==10 evaluates to boolean True, and with PHP's loose typing $i equates to true with a value of $1. If $i has a value of 0, ($i==1 && $j==10) still equates to boolean True, but the loose typing comparison is against $i of 0, which equates to boolean false.... therefore no match

Comment: Is it because the case "2" types $i as a string and then $i == 1 becomes true == true if $i is not empty?

Answer (score 10):

The `switch` statement works by evaluating each `case` expression in turn and comparing the result to the `switch` expression. If the two expressions are equivalent, the case block is executed (within the constraints established by `break`/`continue` constructs). You can use this fact to include arbitrary boolean expressions as `case` expressions. For example:

```
<?php

$i = 3;
$k = 'hello world';

switch (true) {
    case 3 == $i and $k == 'hi there';
        echo "first case is true\n";
    break;

    case 3 == $i and $k == 'hello world';
        echo "second case is true\n";
    break;
} //switch

?>
```

This outputs:

```
second case is true
```

I don't use this sort of construction very often (instead preferring to avoid such complex logic), but it sometimes comes up where a complicated `if-then` statement might otherwise be used, and can make such snippets much easier to read.

Answer (score 2):

What's wrong with simply nesting switches?

```
$i = 1;
$j = 10;

switch($i) {
    case 2:
        echo "The value is 2";
        break;
    case 1:
        switch($j) {
            case 10:
                echo "Exception Case";
                break;
            default:
                echo "The value is 1";
                break;
        }
        break;
    default:
        echo "Invalid";
        break;
}
```

Comment: its boring, try one of starx, its quicker